# PrimeNg schedule don't show minutes of roudend hours

Tags: primeng

I have an `schedule` from `primeNg` on my page, like this:

```
  <p-schedule #schedule  [defaultDate]="dataSelecionada"[defaultView]="'month'" [header]="schedulerHeader"  [events]="events" ></p-schedule>
```

The `events` are showing correctly, but when de `time` is rounded, like `10:00`  or `11:00`, the `schedule` dont display the minutes part (display like this `10`), but I want to display it.

I tried to use `moment.js` to send a formated date to schedule but doesn't work, the schedule don't display anything.

What i tried so far :

```
 moment(evento.dataAgendamento).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
```

and if a pass only `moment(evento.dataAgendamento)` i have the same inital behavior, the minutes don't show

the  `evento.dataAgendamento` property is returning  like `2018-07-09 08:00:00`, but on schedule only show `08`.

If some could help me i would really appreciate, Thanks.

Comment: Can you fork this template and reproduce for us https://stackblitz.com/github/primefaces/primeng-issue-template

Comment: I solved my problem by showing the time on the tittle and hidden the time part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find a way to customize the timeFormat using `schedule`, and this is what i did :

use these `CSS` to hide the time part of the calendar:

```
:host >>> .fc-time { display: none; }
:host >>> .fc-axis.fc-time { display: table-cell; }
```

and then I put the time before te tittle:

```
  this.events = agenda.map(evento => {
  return {
    'title':moment(evento.dataAgendamento).format('HH:mm') + ' ' + evento.agendaGrupo.nome 
    'start': evento.dataAgendamento,
  };
});
```

This for sure isn't the best solution but it works for me.